# ruby on rails reinsert html tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags

I'm getting a document from my database in xml format like this

[link to xml document](http://www.fonsiuris.net/dts/document_endpoint/urn:cts:frenchLit:ed_ruelle:1962:19.xml)

It contains these things &lt p &gt (I removed the semicolumn as this website also transforms it in

).

Is there ruby or a specific rails function that allows to rewrite the correct html tags ? Or must I do a regex for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using in **erb file** then do as,

```
<%= raw "&lt;p&gt;Sacent tout cil ki cest escrit veront et oront ke mesire Engerrans, curés de Waneheng, et Jehans Vrouars, de Waneheng doivent cescuns comme se propre dette et cescuns pour le tout a Jehans le Petit, cousturier de dras u a celui ki cest escrit aporteroit, lai homme, IIIc de faissiaus de gros et de lonc a le clauwiere de Tournai, a paiier XV jours devant le jour Saint Jehans Baptiste ki vient prochainement u XV jours apriés la endevens, en tous leur boins poins et livret en Tournai sour kauchie en quel liu ke li dis Jehans li cousturiers vorra, mais ke kars u karete i puist tourner et kariier.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Et se li dis Jehans li Petis en faisoit coust u frais u despens u emprunt par le defaute de leur paiement, rendre li doivent li deteur dessus dit parmi sen voir dit sans ceste dette amenrir et si poroit li dis Jehans li Petis u chius ki cest escrit aporteroit, lais hons, donner sour le detteurs dessus dit a quel signeur de tiere u a quel bailliu u a quele justice k'il vorroit le quint denier que li value des faissiaus monteroit pour le sien faire avoir d'iaus et ce quint seroient il tenut de paiier avuec le dette devant dite. De tout chou ont il assenet a aus et au leur a quank'il ont et aront partout et cescuns pour le tout.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;La fu Jakemes Brande con voirs jurés et Jakemes le Cuveliers li Agneliers, ki tiesmongna k'il connoiste les parties, comme autres hons. Et si furent les parties a ces escit livrer.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;L'an de grasse mil CCC et XIIII le witisme jour dou mois de march, par un samedi&lt;/p&gt;"%>
```

**Output:**

Sacent tout cil ki cest escrit veront et oront ke mesire Engerrans, curés de Waneheng, et Jehans Vrouars, de Waneheng doivent cescuns comme se propre dette et cescuns pour le tout a Jehans le Petit, cousturier de dras u a celui ki cest escrit aporteroit, lai homme, IIIc de faissiaus de gros et de lonc a le clauwiere de Tournai, a paiier XV jours devant le jour Saint Jehans Baptiste ki vient prochainement u XV jours apriés la endevens, en tous leur boins poins et livret en Tournai sour kauchie en quel liu ke li dis Jehans li cousturiers vorra, mais ke kars u karete i puist tourner et kariier.

Et se li dis Jehans li Petis en faisoit coust u frais u despens u emprunt par le defaute de leur paiement, rendre li doivent li deteur dessus dit parmi sen voir dit sans ceste dette amenrir et si poroit li dis Jehans li Petis u chius ki cest escrit aporteroit, lais hons, donner sour le detteurs dessus dit a quel signeur de tiere u a quel bailliu u a quele justice k'il vorroit le quint denier que li value des faissiaus monteroit pour le sien faire avoir d'iaus et ce quint seroient il tenut de paiier avuec le dette devant dite. De tout chou ont il assenet a aus et au leur a quank'il ont et aront partout et cescuns pour le tout.

La fu Jakemes Brande con voirs jurés et Jakemes le Cuveliers li Agneliers, ki tiesmongna k'il connoiste les parties, comme autres hons. Et si furent les parties a ces escit livrer.

L'an de grasse mil CCC et XIIII le witisme jour dou mois de march, par un samedi

If you are using in controller then use,

```
include ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper

raw("&lt;p&gt;Sacent tout cil ki cest escrit veront et oront ke mesire Engerrans, curés de Waneheng, et Jehans Vrouars, de Waneheng doivent cescuns comme se propre dette et cescuns pour le tout a Jehans le Petit, cousturier de dras u a celui ki cest escrit aporteroit, lai homme, IIIc de faissiaus de gros et de lonc a le clauwiere de Tournai, a paiier XV jours devant le jour Saint Jehans Baptiste ki vient prochainement u XV jours apriés la endevens, en tous leur boins poins et livret en Tournai sour kauchie en quel liu ke li dis Jehans li cousturiers vorra, mais ke kars u karete i puist tourner et kariier.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Et se li dis Jehans li Petis en faisoit coust u frais u despens u emprunt par le defaute de leur paiement, rendre li doivent li deteur dessus dit parmi sen voir dit sans ceste dette amenrir et si poroit li dis Jehans li Petis u chius ki cest escrit aporteroit, lais hons, donner sour le detteurs dessus dit a quel signeur de tiere u a quel bailliu u a quele justice k'il vorroit le quint denier que li value des faissiaus monteroit pour le sien faire avoir d'iaus et ce quint seroient il tenut de paiier avuec le dette devant dite. De tout chou ont il assenet a aus et au leur a quank'il ont et aront partout et cescuns pour le tout.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;La fu Jakemes Brande con voirs jurés et Jakemes le Cuveliers li Agneliers, ki tiesmongna k'il connoiste les parties, comme autres hons. Et si furent les parties a ces escit livrer.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;L'an de grasse mil CCC et XIIII le witisme jour dou mois de march, par un samedi&lt;/p&gt;")
```

**Or you can also use like,**

```
CGI.unescapeHTML "&lt;p&gt;"
```

**Output:**

"

"